# Nagios action_url: Make it a pop-up with more than one URL?

Tags: nagios

We'd like to use the "action_url" in a Nagios configuration file to pop up a small window that allows the user to select one of two URLs.  (I can imagine that if this is implemented, management might request more, but two for now.)  I thought I had a workable (though poor) solution, but in the best case it adds one empty tab to the browser and pops up the small window, and in the worst case it simply opens two tabs, one with the two URLs, the other empty.

Originally I thought this was possible without modifying source code, now I'm not so sure.  Functionality similar to the "AddThis" button I've seen around would be perfect, but it may need a level of control not possible using the "action_url" string.

Alternatively, a second action_url would be sufficient as well, and if I need to modify source code, that's the direction I'll take.

So, does anyone know if this is possible without modifying Nagios source code, or do I simply need to go into the source and add a second action_url directive?

Thanks,

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to use Nagios CGI Includes: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/cgiincludes.html

So you can add a custom JavaScript to your Nagios Web interface, and reference it from your `action_url` property in service or host definitions.

Answer (score 0):

In your apache2 configuration file in /etc/apache2/conf.d make sure you do :

```
<Directory "/<yournagiosDIR>/sbin">
   Options ExecCGI +Includes
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all    
   AuthName "Nagios Access"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /<yournagiosDIR>/etc/htpasswd.users
   Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

For the SBIN Dir you have to do ExecCGI and +Includes.
Else it won't include the SSI in your CGI files.